# Facing Problem Insert Session id In my Database

Tags: arrays, laravel, session, controller, session-cookies

I create session id randomly in my controller,but i can't store my session id in my database .I got an error Like this **Trying to access array offset on value of type null**. Thanks

```
public  function  addtocart(Request $request){
        $cart=New Cart();
        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        if (!isset($session_id)) {
            $session_id = str_random(40);
            Session::put('session_id', $session_id);
        }
        $cart->product_id=$request['product_id'];
        $cart->product_name=$request['product_name'];
        $cart->product_code=$request['product_code'];
        $cart->product_color=$request['product_color'];
        $cart->price=$request['price'];
        $cart->size=$request['size'];
        $cart->quantity=$request['quantity'];
        $cart-> $request['session_id'];
        $cart->save();
        return $cart;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Laravel take care of your session ID? You could use `Session::getId()` to get the session ID.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$cart->session_id = $request['session_id'];`?

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you store the session id in the `$session_id` variable.

You then call `$cart-> $request['session_id']` which tries to access the `$request['session_id']` property. I'm not sure if this is valid PHP but I am sure that this property does not exist.

I assume that wat you want to do is:

```php
$cart->session_id = $session_id
```